# Does writing onPress={onPress()} have anything to do with iife?

Tags: javascript, react-native

If I write onPress below, when I click the button, the console will write test. But if I write onPress(), it writes a test on the console as the page renders. Does writing onPress() have anything to do with iife? Is that why it works without being called the moment the page is rendered?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

const Screen = () => {

    const onPress = () =>{
        console.log('test')
    }

    return (
        <Button title='button' onPress={onPress()}/>
    )
};

export default Screen;
```

Comment: no. but you are assigning `onPress` to be the return value of calling `onPress()` not to the function itself. (if `onPress()` returned a function this would work, but right now it assisgns `undefined` to the Button onPress prop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `onPress={onPress()}` is not an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE).¹ It *is* a function invocation: You're calling `onPress` and using its return value as the value of the `onPress` prop. So you see the console message when the component is rendered, since that function call happens during rendering, and you don't see it when pressing the button, because there's no `press` handler on the button (since `onPress` doesn't return one).

To have `onPress` called when the button is pressed, use `onPress={onPress}` (no `()` after it):

```
return (
    <Button title='button' onPress={onPress}/>
);
```

That assigns your `onPress` function to the `onPress` prop, telling the button to call it when the button is pressed.

---

¹ An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is where you both *create* and *call* the function at the same time, like this:

```
(() => console.log("Hi"))();
```

The `() => console.log("Hi")` part creates the function, and the `(...)()` part calls it.

Answer (score 1):

`onPress` handler expects a function which will `it will` execute on `press` event.

Since in first case, you passing the function object and not executing it,  it is working fine.

But in second case, since you executing by yourself, onPress expects that it will receive the function from the output of your `onPress` event.

You can change it below and it will work

```
<Button title='button' onPress={() => onPress()}/>
```

or

```
<Button title='button' onPress={onPress()}/>


const onPress = () => {
     
    return () => console.log('test'); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No in JS when you want to create an arrow function it should always be pointed out, so now for example

```
return (
    <Button title='button' onPress={onPress()}/>
  )
```

will auto execute because it is an [assignmentOperation](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators) so you can use

```
return (
    <Button title='button' onPress={() => onPress()}/>
  )
```